# Displaying MJPEG url in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, mjpeg

I tried to display a "mjpeg webcam url" on my javafx application but nothing shows

Code is:

```
@FXML
private MediaView mediaView;

...

Media media = new Media("http://192.165.96.36/mjpg/video.mjpg");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);    
player.setAutoPlay(true);
mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
mediaView.setVisible(true);
```

Do you know how can I display mjpeg url videos ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only the following [video formats are supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm):

> FLV containing VP6 video and MP3 audio; MPEG-4 multimedia container with H.264/AVC (Advanced Video Coding) video compression

So you'll first have to transcode your video to h.264 (try `ffmpeg`).

Answer (score 0):

As a comitter of the mjpegstreamer OpenSource project I'd recommend to try
out the latest version of:

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.mjpegstreamer

As of 2019-02 it's being ported to JavaFX. You might want to raise issues as you see needs that are not fullfilled.

Since it's opensource you can also see how the mjpeg videos are handled.